# Is it a good practice to leave function arguments empty, if the function always has the same input?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a function

```
var addOneToArray = function(arr) {
  return arr.push(1);
};
```

If *arr* is always going to be the same in the program (let's say it's always *myArray*), does it make sense to do this instead:

```
var addOneToArray = function() {
  return myArray.push(1);
};
```

What I'm wondering is, is there any added value to doing the latter in terms of speed or something else? Or is it better to have a more generic function, that maybe gets reused?

Comment: It depends, there's no one right answer. If `addOneToArray` is only supposed to work on `myArray`, it's less complicated to not pass in `myArray` as an argument every time you use it, but that's just a simple response to a simple example, hard to extrapolate as a general rule. Re speed: Don't worry about it until/unless you have a performance problem in front of you to solve (which is *extremely* unlikely to be related to whether you used the first or second version of the above).

Comment: For unit testing second one will be better.Also a funcion should follow the *S.O.L.I.D* principle

Comment: It is bad practice to replace function arguments with globals. A function with obvious inputs and outputs is easier to read, understand, reuse and test.

Comment: If you do do the latter (no arguments) then the function name should reflect this: addOneToArray should take an argument but addOneToMyArray won't

Comment: An engineer's ability to predict what will always be true is always faulty

Comment: @brk In which way do you think does this function hurt a SOLID principle?

Answer (score -1):

If you have the only method that needs to executed then it would be fine. But when you have to implement multiple methods related to same object (in our case Array object) it is always fine to have own constructor for the same.

You can use something like,

```
var customArray = function() {}
customArray.prototype = Array.prototype; // Make it to behave like Array
```

Now, `customArray` is same as the Array class. You can add your method as

```
customArray.prototype.addOneToArray = function() {
   this.push(1);
};
```

How you can use it,

```
var arr = new customArray();
arr.addOneToArray();
```